# regex, how to allow spaces

Tags: php

Here it is:

```
'/^\b[a-z]{0,20}$/i'
```

I'm trying to match work positions:

```
"Employee", "Daily Manager"++.
```

I need to allow `A-Za-z` + spaces and lenght from `0-20`

Any help?

Comment: You should read up on [character classes](http://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html), that's what `[a-z]` is, and what they do.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What about

```
'/^\b[a-z ]{0,20}$/i'
```

Answer (score 2):

`'/^\b[a-z ]{0,20}$/i'` simple

Comment: `A-Z` is unnecessary since `/i` makes match case insensitive

Answer (score 0):

```
[\w ]{0,20}
```

Furthermore `\s` covers all white spaces.

Comment: `\w` will also match numbers and underscores